# Update table with new data coming from CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been working on updating whole rows of Persons2 (let's say) with the data coming from a CTE. What would be the easiest way to perform this action?

The code I am using is below, I am getting some data from the CTE which uses the `Persons1` and `Persons2` tables. After the result obtained I want to insert the whole data (rows) into `Persons2` (do not need the previous data in Persons2).

**Case1:** If I am doing this, the duplicate data is adding to the Persons2 (it is just inserting the new data with out performing deleting, delete command is not allowing me here)

Your solutions are most valuable to me, Thank you.

```html
;WITH tabtemp AS 
(
    SELECT
        COALESCE(p1.id, p2.id) AS ID,
        COALESCE(p1.name, p2.name) AS Name,
        COALESCE(p1.phnumber, p2.phnumber) AS PHNumber,
        CASE 
            WHEN p1.name IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS IsActive
    FROM 
        Persons1 p1
    FULL JOIN 
        Persons2 p2 ON p1.name = p2.name
                    AND p1.phnumber = p2.phnumber)
INSERT INTO Persons2 (ID, Name, PHNumber, IsActive)
    SELECT * 
    FROM tabtemp
```

Comment: Why not use update instead of insert if p2 data exists?

Comment: [Read about `MERGE` (2008+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So actually, you need to add the new data in P1 which not already in p2. 
Add the Where condition blew:

```
;WITH tabtemp AS (SELECT
    COALESCE(p1.id, p2.id) AS ID,
    COALESCE(p1.name, p2.name) AS Name,
    COALESCE(p1.phnumber, p2.phnumber) AS PHNumber,
    CASE WHEN p1.name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsActive
FROM Persons1 p1
FULL JOIN persons2 p2
    ON p1.name = p2.name
    AND p1.phnumber = p2.phnumber)
Insert Into Persons2(ID,Name,PHNumber,IsActive)
SELECT * FROM tab temp

where p2.id is null -- Added
```

you can also use the MERGE Statement.

Comment: But this would not update existing rows. If one column in p2 is ´NULL` where p1 has got a value, this should be updated (at least I suppose so...)

Comment: It will only add the records in the p1 thats not exist in p2 to the records already in p2.

Comment: If this is all OP needs, it was easier with a simple `WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)`

Comment: @Ahmed Saeed - Here i want to update p2 where cte gives combined values of  p1 & p2.